# Pass variables between two controllers in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xib

I would like to pass some variables from my first controller:

```
float user_distance;
UIImage *user;
float user_battery;
NSString *user_name;
```

To a second controller. 
The connection between the two is made by the function:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

in this manner:

```
    UserViewController *secondViewController = [[UserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

How is it possible to recover the values in from this function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You manage the dataSource, so from the `indexPath`, you can retrieve the value of your (array?) dataSource. You may now set theses values to `secondViewController`.

Comment: how can I retrieve the value of my first variable for example from the indexpath?

Comment: It depends on how you code `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: `secondViewController.device = [self.arrayOfDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` Then? With `UserViewController` having a property `device` of class `SEC_Device`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the properties you need to your second controller in your .h file ..

```
//SecondController.h    
@interface SecondController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) float *property1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *property2;
@property (nonatomic) float *property3;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *property4;
@end
```

Then import your second controller .h file in your first controller .m file..
And set the properties before pushing the second controller.

```
//FirstController.m
#import "SecondController.h"
...
...
UserViewController *secondViewController = [[UserViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UserViewController" bundle:nil];

secondViewController.property1 = ;//your value here
secondViewController.property2 = ;//your value here
secondViewController.property3 = ;//your value here
secondViewController.property4 = ;//your value here

[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Yes that's good thanks ! there is just a little mistake, in fact there is no " * " for the declaration of the float !